# I want to search data with search bar data I have received from firebase database into recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search data with search bar data I have  received from firebase database into recyclerview...

I am trying to search data through edit text and search from received from database text . But failed can u please tell me how can I do it here is my code. I have tried more than 4 hours but :(

---

> eco.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="search!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView tools:context="Controller.MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> recyclerview_item.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textColor="#000000"
     />
```

> Eco.java

```
   public class Eco extends AppCompatActivity {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        EditText editText;
        ScrollView textViewWrapper;
        Button button;
        TextView textView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_eco);
           textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textViewWrapper = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWrapper);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //textView.setText(R.string.longText);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            new Eco.GetDataFromFirebase().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            // Read from the database
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("F");

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    /*for (DataSnapshot alert: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(alert.getValue());
                    }*/
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.
                    ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(values));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    System.out.println("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
                }
            });
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String criteria = editText.getText().toString();
                    String fullText = textView.getText().toString();
                    if (fullText.contains(criteria)) {
                        int indexOfCriteria = fullText.indexOf(criteria);
                        int lineNumber = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(indexOfCriteria);
                        String highlighted = "<font color='red'>"+criteria+"</font>";
                        fullText = fullText.replace(criteria, highlighted);
                        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullText));

                        textViewWrapper.scrollTo(0, textView.getLayout().getLineTop(lineNumber));
                    }
                }
            });
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                        String fullText = textView.getText().toString();
                        fullText = fullText.replace("<font color='red'>", "");
                        fullText = fullText.replace("</font>", "");
                        textView.setText(fullText);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
        }

        private class GetDataFromFirebase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to search for data or filter data in your recyclerview? If you want to filter data, then you should add the code in your recyclerview adapter too

Comment: received  data... I don't know about difference b/w data or filter data

Comment: To filter data, you retrieve data from your database and pass it to your recyclerview, and then you use code to show only the recyclerview items that hold similar data to the data that you're searching for. To search for data only, you send your search data to your database and it send you back with only data from the database that matches your search data and then you can place it in your recyclerview

Comment: how can u plz show me the code

Comment: I shared your question with a colleague and he told me that you must have already retrieved data from firebase and now you want to filter it. I'll help with the code that i know, but most of the code is in your recyclerview and not in your activity class

Comment: See this question here [RecyclerView List items Search using EditText implementing filterable do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648714/recyclerview-list-items-search-using-edittext-implementing-filterable-do-not-wor) also see [Search Functionality in RecyclerView using EditText](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/search-functionality-recyclerview/)